# Custom directive v-focus on input with v-show in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I registered a custom directive for focusing input. I use the code from [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html):

```
// Register a global custom directive called v-focus
Vue.directive('focus', {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
  inserted: function (el) {
    // Focus the element
    el.focus()
  }
})
```

And the I apply `v-focus` on these elements:

```
<input v-show="isInputActive" v-focus>

<div v-show="isDivActive">
  <input v-focus>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work. It works only if I replace `v-show` with `v-if` but I have to use `v-show`. Is there a solution?

Comment: Your element isn't re-rendered each time the condition inside the `v-show` directive is valued as `true`. See the documentation here for more information : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show

Comment: I knew that, infact I'm asking how to use v-focus with v-show

Comment: Does it work with `v-if`? It should re-render then...

Comment: With v-if it works but I need to use the v-show

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a value to v-focus, then add a update hook function:

```js
Vue.directive("focus", {
  inserted: function(el) {
    // Focus the element
    el.focus()
  },
  update: function(el, binding) {
    var value = binding.value;
    if (value) {
      Vue.nextTick(function() {
        el.focus();
      });
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      ifShow: true
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <input type="text" v-focus="ifShow" v-show="ifShow">
  <br>
  <button @click="ifShow = !ifShow">toggle</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution should be you can `focus` when `isInputActive` or `isDivActive` change.

```
<input v-show="isInputActive" v-ref="input">

watch: {
  isInputChange(value) {
    if (value) this.$refs.input.focus()
  }
}
```